# C# - Inserting Dictionary Keys/Values into New Tuple

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, tuples

I've read some similar posts, but many are just asking about inserting dictionaries into tuples and vice versa.  My issue is that I have two separate dictionaries that I want to use to fill in a new tuple.

The the two dictionaries have some common information, which is the user's email.  The `addressBook` dictionary holds the user's name and the user's email.  The `usersAndManagersList` holds the user's email and the manager's email.  I was hoping to match up the two then put all bits of information into a single tuple to easily pass around this instead of two dictionaries.

```
public static Tuple<string, string, string> allUserInformation(Dictionary<string, string> addressBook, Dictionary<string, string> usersAndManagersList)
    {
        Tuple<string, string, string> allUserInfo;

        foreach (var thing in addressBook)
        {
            foreach (var that in usersAndManagersList)
            {
                if (thing.Value == that.Key)
                {
                    var userName = thing.Key;
                    var userEmail = thing.Value;
                    var managerEmail = that.Value;

                    Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, User's Email: {1}, Manager's Email: {2}", userName, userEmail, managerEmail);

                    allUserInfo = Tuple.Create(userName, userEmail, managerEmail);
                }
            }
        }

        return allUserInfo; 
    }
```

The values in the `addressBook` and the keys in the `usersAndManagersList` are both the users' emails.  I was trying to loop through everything and if the values of one match up with the keys of the other, then the user's email, user's name, and manager's email will be used to create a tuple, then starts over in the loop.

Main struggles: I'm stuck if I should use a `while` or `if` loop.  I'm worried about scope and where exactly should I `return` the tuple.  An error I've gotten is that I'm returning an empty/unassigned tuple, which I understand why based on where I returned it, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  How do I create this tuple with the right loops, etc.?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, please fix. I assume you want to iterate over `addressBook` and `usersAndManagersList`, NOT over the `Values` and `Keys` of each, and also that you want to do `if (thing.Value == that.Key)`, but I don't know for sure. Additionally, try to use better variable names than `thing` and `that`.

Comment: You should just take the address book and join it on the usersAndManagersList and then just select the tupple in the result selector

Comment: You are returning a `Tuple<string, string, string>`, that will only have one set of values, I think you need to return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string>>`, basically an array of `Tuple`. You may also want to look at Linq, this could quite succinctly enumerate your data and return what you want.

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of an `if` loop ;).

Comment: @Quantic: Yes, I made a mistake and was going to add in the thing.Value, that.Key, etc.  I am just using `thing` and `that` as temporary placeholders to quickly get the structure of what I wanted.  Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the code.  @Owain Williams:  I was hoping to add another method towards the end to just pick up one tuple at a time, so I wouldn't need to deal with an array...saying this, I might not need to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join or a where statement to match them on a condition and then select the tuple from the results selector.  Join is a more complicated logic but has better performance.  While the where is more readable to most people

```
//Assuming that addressBook value (the users email) is the key for the usersAndManagersList

var results = addressBook.Join(usersAndManagersList, addr => addr.Value, user => user.Key, (a, u) => {
    var userName = a.Key;
    var userEmail = a.Value;
    var managerEmail = u.Value;
    return Tuple.Create(userName, userEmail, managerEmail);
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with joining dictionaries - with this approach, would I stick this part into the two `foreach` loops?  Is that how it would work?

Comment: in the var Results would be a list of the tuples you created, you don't need the foreaches at all anymore

Comment: I like this approach best, though I ended up using objects instead of dictionaries and tuples.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks it should very efficient

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want with LINQ:

```
addressBook.Where(a => usersAndManagersList.ContainsKey(a.Value))
    .Select(a => Tuple.Create(a.Key, a.Value, usersAndManagersList[a.Value]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that JRLambert answer is the best I desided to put some very long and "classic" approach which might be more readable for somebody who don't know LINQ.

```
   class Program
```

{

```
  public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string> > AllUserInformation(Dictionary<string, string> addressBook, Dictionary<string, string> usersAndManagersList)
  {
     foreach (var book in addressBook)
     {
        string managerEmail;
        if (usersAndManagersList.TryGetValue(book.Value, out managerEmail))
        {
           yield return Tuple.Create(book.Key, book.Value, managerEmail);
        }
        else
        {
           yield return Tuple.Create(book.Key, book.Value, string.Empty);
        }
     }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Dictionary<string, string> addressBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     Dictionary<string, string> usersAndManagersList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     addressBook.Add("Andy", "andy@firm.com");
     addressBook.Add("Mary", "mary@firm.com");
     usersAndManagersList.Add("andy@firm.com", "jane@firm.com");

     foreach (var allInfo in AllUserInformation(addressBook, usersAndManagersList))
     {
        Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, User's Email: {1}, Manager's Email: {2}", allInfo.Item1, allInfo.Item2, allInfo.Item3);
     }
  }
```

}